# Is my code correctly portraying the diagram?

Tags: c, if-statement

[image]

What my function does, is it takes the values of the profit (function declared as fieldProfit) and the field score (function declared as fieldScore); and if both are above 10, then you earn a badge, hence, innerbadge = 1. BUT, there's also another condition that must be met, the field or (x, y) coordinates, have to fall in the area depicted as the shaded in box that has a hole in the middle. I've written the code for it, and I just wanted to make sure that my logic/syntax is correct! Any help is appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
int badgeInnerCircle(int x, int y) {
   double fprofit, fscore;
   int innerbadge;

   if ((x >= 1 && x <= 20) && (y >= 1 && y <= 20)) {
      if (((x == 7 || x == 8) && (y >= 7 && y <= 14)) || ((x == 13 || x == 14)
         && (y >= 7 && y <= 14)) || ((x >= 7 && x <= 14) && (y == 7 || y == 8))
            || ((x >= 7 && x <= 14) && (y == 13 || y == 14))) {
         fprofit = fieldProfit(x, y);
         fscore = fieldScore(x, y);
         if (fprofit >= 10 && fscore >= 10) {
            innerbadge = 1;
         }
         else {
            innerbadge = 0;
         }
      }
   }
   else {
      innerbadge = -1;
   }
   return innerbadge;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no, your code is not correct.

```
int innerbadge;

if (condition) {
  if (condition) {
    if (condition) {
      innerbadge = 1;
    }
    else {
      innerbadge = 0;
    }
  }
  //else unidentified!
}
else {
  innerbadge = -1;
}
```

you should change the initialisazion to "int innerbadge = 0;" or something approriate